# Possible errors in a code at matlab about a function

Tags: matlab, sum

Let Sn = 8Σ (1/((4κ-3)(4κ-1))). It is known that lim of Sn when n tends to infinitive is equal to pi.
Write a function [sn,n] = mySumPi(tol) which outputs Sn and n for the smallest n such that absolute value of Sn-pi

I have written the following code but it seems that it does not work.

```
function [sn,n] = mySumPi(tol)
%[sn,n] = mySumPi(tol)
%lim as n approaches infinity is pi
% n is the smallest numbers such that the abs(sn-pi) <tol
count = 0;
sn=0
while abs(sn-pi) >= tol
    sn = sn + (8*sn)*(((4*n)-3)*((4*n)-1)) 
    count = count+1;
    n = count - 1;   
end
end
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: >> mySumPi
Unrecognized function or variable 'sn'.

Error in mySumPi (line 6)
while abs(sn-pi) >= tol

Comment: You use sn before you initialize it. Since sn is a sum, you probably want to start with sn=0.

Comment: ok i edited it... if i add sn=0 i get this error : >> [sn,n]=mySumPi(0.1)
Unrecognized function or variable 'n'.

Error in mySumPi (line 8)
    sn = sn + (8*sn)*(((4*n)-3)*((4*n)-1))

Comment: Same error, you use n before you initialize it

Comment: how can i define n?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the code below.

```
function [sn,n] = mySumPi(tol)
n = 1; 
sn = 0;
while 1 % repeat the procedure until the termination condition is valid
  sn = sn + 8/(((4*n)-3)*((4*n)-1)); % you had wrong formula in you code
  if abs(sn-pi) < tol % termination condition
    break;
  else
    n = n + 1;
  end
end
end
```

such that

```
>> [sn,n] = mySumPi(1e-1)
sn =  3.0418
n =  5

>> [sn,n] = mySumPi(1e-3)
sn =  3.1406
n =  500

>> [sn,n] = mySumPi(1e-5)
sn =  3.1416
n =  50000
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! really!! Could i tell you one more exercise where i am stack if you could help me?

Comment: Write a programme to plot the function () =  sin((9 + 1))over the interval [−1,1] using increments in of (a) 0.2, (b) 0.1, and (c) 0.01. The programme should plot the three graphs in the same figure. Include the legend to specify which graph corresponds to which increment. (Observe that the plots for cases (a) and (b) give
totally the wrong picture of ().)

Comment: @OpilsoulEnglish I suggest you create a new post for your question, instead of the comment area here

Comment: could u give me a hint?

Comment: @OpilsoulEnglish some commands you may need: `x = -1:0.2:1` (you can change the increment for you three cases),`plot`, `legend`, `hold on`

Comment: if i write it as a different question would u help me more?

Comment: It is definitely worth looking at the functions and especially the examples in the documentation, but if you struggle with these, please create a new question. I am sure someone will help you.

Comment: @OpilsoulEnglish yes, please